# Sum of dot product of unit vectors

Tags: vectors

if $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, $\vec{c}$ are unit vectors and $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} + \vec{b} \cdot \vec{c} + \vec{c} \cdot \vec{a} = -\frac{3}{2}$.

Is there possibilities that $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}, \vec{b} \cdot \vec{c}$ and $\vec{c} \cdot \vec{a}$ have values other than  $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = \vec{b} \cdot \vec{c} = \vec{c} \cdot \vec{a} = -\frac{1}{2}$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, there is not. Remember that $a\cdot b = b\cdot a$.

Proof: If $a\cdot b + b\cdot c + c\cdot a = -\frac{3}{2}$, then, for $a\cdot a = b\cdot b = c\cdot c = 1$, we have that
$$
     a\cdot a + b\cdot b + c\cdot c + 2(a\cdot b + b\cdot c + c\cdot a) = -3 + 3 = 0
$$
i.e.
$$
     (a + b + c)\cdot (a + b + c) = 0.
$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
a + b + c = 0 &\Rightarrow b + c = - a\\ 
&\Rightarrow \vert b + c\vert = 1\\
&\Rightarrow \vert b\vert + \vert c\vert + 2b\cdot c = 1\\
&\Rightarrow b\cdot c = -\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}
Similarly we prove that $a\cdot b = c\cdot a = b\cdot c = -\frac{1}{2}$.